# Dynamically display User Input as tool-tip in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I want to take 12 inputs from the user using multiple areas in a popup dialog box.I want these inputs to be shown as tool-tips for multiple points of this graph
      http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-labels 
Whichever examples i have come across till now don't mention anything about how to do this.Does anyone have any idea how to implement tooltips using text-area input given by user ???

Comment: How are the input and the graph points related each others?

Comment: From the 12 inputs taken,the first input will be the tool-tip text of 1st graph point,2nd input will be tool-tip text of 2nd graph point so on and so forth..The graph points will not be taken from the user,only the alphanumeric characters which will be displayed as tool-tip will be taken from the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`tooltip formatter`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter) option of the chart to render a custom tooltip for each point of the graph.
In my example for every point I get the corresponding value of the nth input using [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) selector and use its value in the tooltip.

The code look like this:

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        var index = dataValues.indexOf(this.y);
        var comment=$("input:eq("+(index)+")").val()
        return 'The value for <b>'+ this.x +
            '</b> is <b>'+ this.y +'</b> -->'+comment;
    }
},
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/RbenU/1/

Obviously you can change the logic according to your needs.

Comment: In your js fiddle you have used only one series and stored it's values in a variable called dataValues.I want to have 2 series in my graph like in link i posted.O in that case do i have to create 2 more variables besides index,comment to store the tool tip for another series???

Comment: @Lucy here is a fiddle with two series http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/RbenU/2/ you can use the this.series.index to know what serie is rendering I stored them in variabiles for a simple access to them if you need to get them from the graph object let me know and we found a solution

Comment: I want to take input from text-areas instead of text boxes.These text areas will be displayed in a pop-up dialog box for input of data..Points of series 1 and 2 falling under the same month will have same tooltip...I have been able to do the latter part i.e. making points under the same month have same tooltip in this fidddle http://jsfiddle.net/RbenU/3/ I need help in converying text-boxes to text-areas and make them appear in a popup dialog box...

Comment: Modifying your example to use textarea instead of inputs is really easy (see: http://jsfiddle.net/RbenU/15/). Putting them in popup is just a css. You should be able to do this on your own

Comment: @slawekkolodziej yes I have been able able to do that http://jsfiddle.net/RbenU/20/..The only problem i am facing is that points in every month should have same tooltip and every point of a particular series should have different tooltip even if their values are same but i am not being able to do that...

Comment: But you already have everything you need in your code, see: http://jsfiddle.net/RbenU/21/

Comment: I mean that the points under the Jan month should have "1st comment" as tooltip,points under Feb should have "2nd comment" as tooltip even if 2 points of series 1 have same value..but that is not happening in the code of your link...That is waht i am trying to change..

Comment: @Lucy If you have a new questions to ask do it; this I think can be accepted

Comment: thanks..I found the answer i was looking for in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16538725/trouble-getting-unique-tooltip-based-on-x-axis-values-in-highcharts-line-graph/16565683#16565683 .@edward thank you for your help...

Comment: If you the question if solved green mark the answer see the [faq#howtoask]

Comment: But are two different questions 1st how do I use tooltipformatter, 2nd I a specific question; sorry if I'm noious but this question is solved as a part of your solution IMHO