# Dynamically Take input from text-areas in a jquery ui custom pop up box for Tooltip in highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, jquery-ui-dialog

I want to take 12 inputs from the user using 12 text-areas.These text-areas should be displayed inside a jquery ui custom pop up dialog box.This pop up dialog box should be visible only on button click.The input so taken should then be displayed as tooltip in a highchart line graph along with word-wrap feature as i want to enter 50 characters in each text box..

I have been able to take input from a user using text-areas but i am having trouble placing these text-areas inside a pop up dialog box using jquery ui.. In highcharts the tooltip is normally loaded on document ready but i want tool tip to be dislplayed only after clicking the button and filling data inside multiple text-areas of the pop up dialog box...

In this link http://jsfiddle.net/RbenU/3/  The code used for tooltip is

```
             tooltip: {
           formatter: function () {
            var serieI = this.series.index;
            var index = dataValues.indexOf(this.y);
           var index1= dataValues2.indexOf(this.y);
           debugger;
            var comment = "";
            if (serieI == 0) {
                comment = $("input:eq(" + (index) + ")").val();
            } else {
               //comment = "second serie matched!";
                comment = $("input:eq(" + (index1) + ")").val();
            }
            return 'The value for <b>' + this.x +
                '</b> is <b>' + this.y + '</b> -->' + comment;
        }
    },
```

I have used only 4 text-boxes as I wanted to display the text-boxes in a pop up dailog box first before moving on to make 12 text-boxes...

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the modal form example here:
* http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form
When the user presses:

```
        ...
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
            "Create an account": function() { 
              //get the form values or post the form here
        ...
```

In general refer to the jQuery examples first to find your needs and use the API for details.

Comment: I haven't used modal form dialog box.I just inserted a few text-areas in a default funtionality dialog box..By doing this I'am able to print their values on a webpage but when I try that their values be used as tooltip in highcharts line graph then I am facing difficulty..Can you please tell how to use values of a text area in a pop up form as tooltip in highcharts??looked at Jquery ui api documentation as well but can't find anything useful for using text-area values as tooltip in highcharts

Comment: checked the documentation..I was able to add tooltip to highchart using textboxes as seen in line "comment = $("input:eq(" + (index) + ")").val();" of the code...The keyword input here is for taking input from textboxes as we use <input type="text" name="txt"/> to define textboxes...but  i wasn't able to figure out how to define a textarea because we use."<textarea id="txt11"rows="2" cols="10" name="ar2"style="resize:none"></textarea>".....                      so i was hoping you could help me in how to write that particular condition for a textarea....

Comment: Create some separate question for this and add the appropriate tags I am sure someone will be able to help

Comment: I did create a separate question for this in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16373013/dynamically-display-user-input-as-tool-tip-in-highcharts but could not get a response so posted it here hoping to get an answer..