# Trouble getting unique tooltip based on X axis values in highcharts line graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, highcharts, tooltip

I'm trying to make a graph in which points having different x axis values have different tooltip .The 1st two points of a series have the same tooltip even though their x axis values are different.i.e points under the month of jan should have "11st comment" tooltip,points under Feb should have "22nd comment" tooltip so on and so forth even if their x axis values are same but not y axis values..

The current computational logic is that the tooltip depends upon the y axis values.As long as y axis values are changing the tool tip changes accordingly.This happens because of the statement"this.y" in the below code..

The problem with this logic is that as long as y axis values are distinct the tooltip works properly,the moment 2 consecutive points of a series have same y axis values the tooltip does not change when their x values are different...

To make the tooltip change acoording to x axis values I am replacing "this.y" with "this.x" but the desired change is not happening.Can you please tell me how to make that change?

The tool tip code..

```
       tooltip: {
       formatter: function () {
        var serieI = this.series.index;
      var index = dataValues.indexOf(this.y);
     var index1= dataValues2.indexOf(this.y);
      debugger;
        var comment = "";
        if (serieI == 0) {
            comment = $("#ppForm.textarea:eq(" + (index) + ")").val();
        } else {
           //comment = "second serie matched!";
            comment = $("#ppForm.textarea:eq(" + (index1) + ")").val();
        }
        /*return ''+ this.x +
            '</b> is <b>' + this.y + '</b> -->' + comment;*/
        return '-->'+comment;
    }
}
```

The js fiddle is... http://jsfiddle.net/RbenU/25/

Comment: the tooltip will, by default, be different for every point as long as the x and y values are different.  There is a *LOT* going on in that fiddle...I think you need to pear it down to the basics and work out your tooltip issue, then add the other stuff back in.

Comment: yes I am aware of that.In my graph i want the tooltip to be based on X axis value.All the points having a partcular x value have one tooltip and points having another x axis value will have another tooltip..But i'm not being able to do that..Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RbenU/5/..it is the simpler version of the fiddle posted in the question..

Comment: I don't know what you are asking then, because that fiddle does exactly what you describe.  Each of the first data points have the same x value and the first tooltip, each of the second data points have the same x value and the second tooltip, etc...   You'll need to clarify what you want and what isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using index for `dataValues` use index for categories, this way: http://jsfiddle.net/RbenU/39/

```
tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            var serieI = this.series.index;
            var index = categories.indexOf(this.x);
            var comment = $("input:eq(" + (index) + ")").val();
            return '-->'+comment;
        }
    },
```